# Progress Bar with Gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Hello I am looking for a signal for gtkmm. Basically I am doing some simulations and what I want is something like this :

I assume I do 5 simulations :

```
progressBar.set_fraction(0);

1 simulation
progressBar.set_fraction(progressBar.get_fraction()+1/5)


2 simulation
progressBar.set_fraction(progressBar.get_fraction()+1/5)


3 simulation
progressBar.set_fraction(progressBar.get_fraction()+1/5)


4 simulation
progressBar.set_fraction(progressBar.get_fraction()+1/5)


5 simulation
progressBar.set_fraction(progressBar.get_fraction()+1/5)
```

But I don't know which signal I have to use and how to translate to this.

Thank you a lot for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code which you presented in your question should actually work - no signal is necessary. However, you could introduce a signal into your simulation for update of the progress bar. IMHO this will not solve your problem and I will try to explain why and what to do to solve it:

You provided a little bit too less context, so, that I will introduce some more assumptions: You have a main window with a button or toolbar item or menu item (or even all of them) which start the simulation.

Let's imagine you set a breakpoint at `Gtk::ProgressBar::set_fraction()`.

Once the debugger stopped at this break point you will find the following calls on the stack trace (probably with many other calls in between):

- Gtk::Main::run()
- the signal handler of the widget or action which started the simulation
- the function which runs the five simulations
- and last the call of `Gtk::ProgressBar::set_fraction()`.

If you could inspect the internals of `Gtk::ProgressBar` you would notice that everything in `Gtk::ProgressBar::set_fraction()` is done properly. So what's wrong?

When you call `Gtk::ProgressBar::set_fraction()` it probably generates an expose event (i.e. adds an event to the event queue inside of `Gtk::Main` with a request for its own refresh). The problem is that you probably do not process the request until all five runs of the simulation are done. (Remember that `Gtk::Main::run()` which is responsible for this is the uppermost/outmost call of my imaginery stack trace.) Thus, the refresh does not happen until the simulation is over - that's too late. (Btw. the authors of Gtk+ stated somewhere in the manual about their cleverness to optimize events. I.e. there might be finally only one expose event for the `Gtk::ProgressBar` in the event queue but this does not make your situation better.)

Thus, after you called `Gtk::ProgressBar::set_fraction()` you must somehow flush the event queue before doing further progress with your simulation.
This sounds like leaving the simulation, leaving the calling widget signal handler, returning to `Gtk::Main::run()` for further event processing and finally coming back for next simulation step - terrible idea. But we did it much simpler. For this, we use essentially the following code (in gtkmm 2.4):

```
while (Gtk::Main::events_pending()) Gtk::Main::iteration(false);
```

(This should hopefully be the same in the gtkmm version you use but if in doubt consult the manual.)

It should be done immediately after updating the progress bar fraction and before simulation is continued.

This recursively enters (parts of) the main loop and processes all pending events in the event queue of `Gtk::Main` and thus, the progress bar is exposed before the simulation continues. You may be concerned to "recursively enter the main loop" but I read somewhere in the GTK+ manual that it is allowed (and reasonable to solve problems like this) and what to care about (i.e. to limit the number of recursions and to grant a proper "roll-back").

What in your case is the simulation we call in general *long running functions*. Because such long running functions are algorithms (in libraries for anything) which shall not be polluted with any GUI stuff, we built some administrational infra structure around this basic concept including

- a progress "proxy" object with an `update(double)` method and a signal slot
- a customized progress dialog which can connect a signal handler to such a progress object (i.e. its signal slot).

The long running function gets a progress object (as argument) and is responsible to call the `Progress::update()` method in appropriate intervals with an appropriate progress factor. (We simply use values in the range [0, 1].)

One issue is the interval of calling the progress update. If it is called to often the GUI will slow down your long running function significantly. The opposite case (calling it not often enough) results in less responsiveness of GUI. Thus, we decided for more often progress update. To lower the time consuming of GUI, we remember the time of last update in our progress dialog and skip the next refreshs until a certain duration since last refresh is measured. Thus, the long running function has still some extra effort for progress update but it is not recognizable anymore. (A good refresh interval is IMHO 0.1 s - the perception threshold of humans but you may choose 0.05 s if in doubt.)

Flushing all pending events results in processing of mouse events (and other GTK+ signals) also. This allows another useful feature: aborting the long running function.

When the "Cancel" button of our progress dialog is pressed it sets an internal flag. If the progress is updated next time it checks the flag. If the flag became `true` it throws a special exception. The throw aborts the caller of the progress update (the long running function) immediately. This exception must be catched in the signal handler of the button (or whatever called the long running function). Otherwise, it would "fall through" to the event dispatcher in `Gtk::Main` where it is catched definitely which would abort your application. (I saw it often enough whenever I forgot to catch.) On the other hand: catching the special exception tells clearly that the long running function has been aborted (in opposition to ended by regulary return). This may or may not be something which can be stated on GUI also.

Finally, the above solution can cause another issue: It enables to start the  simulation (via GUI) while a simulation is already running. This is possible because button presses for simulation start could be processed while in progress update. To prevent this, there is actually a simple solution: set a flag at start of simulation in the GUI until it has finished and prevent further starts while the flag is set. Another option can be to make the widget/action insensitive when simulation is started. This topic becomes more complicated if you have multiple distinct long running functions in your application which may or may not exclude each other - leads to something like an exclusion matrix. Well, we solved it pragmatically... (but without the matrix).

And last but not least I want to mention that we use a similar concept for output of log views (e.g. visual logging of infos, warnings, and errors while anything long running is in progress). IMHO it is always good to provide some visual action for end users. Otherwise, they might get bored and use the telephone to complain about the (too) slow software which actually steals you the time to make it faster (a vicious cycle you have to break...)